# Scan for MFI products over Wi Fi

Tags: wifi, ios8, wifi-direct, mfi

In iOS 8, Apple allows us to connect to a device via Wifi direct and share wifi network credentials with it.
We can do it in wifi settings page but also in an app.

I'm trying to launch a scan to find wifi MFI devices.
I can see those in the wifi settings but not in app.
Here is how I do this:

```
EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser *_wifiBrowser = [[EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
[_wifiBrowser startSearchingForUnconfiguredAccessoriesMatchingPredicate:nil];
```

So I expect to see an accessory in the delegate method

```
- (void)accessoryBrowser:(EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser *)browser didFindUnconfiguredAccessories:(NSSet *)accessories
```

But nothings happens.
Do you know what is missing ?

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found why it did not work well.

You need to go in your Capabilities pannel (by selecting your target)
And then enable Wireless Accessory Configuration !

Comment: Xcode 6.1 adds the capability automatically for a project that links to ExternalAccessory.framework. Quite a nuisance if you only supported Bluetooth/USB/Lightning accessories!

Comment: Good to know! I hadn't download it yet